# Why can't we get a pointer to a generic struct?

Tags: c#, pointers, struct

Why would the inline instantiated struct suddenly become a managed type? Not only is its generic constrained to unmanaged, but the struct itself is fully blittable.

```
public struct MyStruct<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public int SomePrimitive;
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    var mystruct = new MyStruct<int>();
    var myPtr = &mystruct;
}
```

Comment: It works for me (C#8, unsafe build option ticked). What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: You are potentially also missing the unsafe keyword  `public unsafe void DoSomething()`. Also in this instance as shown you don't need the unmanaged constraint

Comment: @SylvainRodrigue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0208
I'm using C#7.3

Comment: honestly, I have never seen the `unmanaged` keyword before. I will look it up.

Answer (score 0):

I was using C# 7.3 (Unity Compatibility). Apparently this exact thing became possible in C# 8.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#unmanaged-constructed-types